When is argmax increasing in some multiplier of the objective function?
Let $f : R_+ \to [0,1]$ be continuously differentiable and strictly increasing with $f(0)=0, \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1$ and let $c : R_+ \to R_+$ be continuously differentiable, strictly increasing, convex, and satisfy $c(0)=c'(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty} c(x)=\lim_{x\to \infty}c'(x)=\infty$.
What conditions on $f$ are needed so that the solution to
$$ \max_{x\in[0,1]} \ \alpha f(x) - c(x) $$
is strictly increasing in $\alpha>0$? (This is certainly true if $f$ is linear.)

You could use the implicit function theorem to show this claim.

You write $c : [0,1] \to R_+
$ and $c(1)=\infty$. There's a contradiction.

apologies, corrected.

@Bertrand I also had a hunch that this was the way to go, but I haven't found an obvious way to do it.

Hint: Consider the first order condition (if the second order conditions are met), this defines implicitly a function that gives argmax as $a$ varies, $x=x^(a)$, using the implicit function theorem you can find the derivative $dx^(a)/da$, and as a consequence the conditions for that derivative to be positive.

Still, a continuous function on a closed and bounded interval must be bounded.

@MichaelGreinecker you're correct again. Hopefully I've fixed it for good. Those conditions were meant to yield an interior solution, but the current set up should do too.

First, we do need additional conditions on $f$ beyond the ones you supplied in the question. Consider $c(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2$ and $f(x)=\tanh x$, both restricted to the domain $\mathbb{R}_+$. These functions satisfy your assumptions. However, there exists some $\bar{\alpha}$ large enough such that for all $\alpha>\bar{\alpha}$, $x^*(\alpha) =\text{argmax}_{x} \  \alpha f(x)-c(x)$ is a corner solution at $x^*(\alpha)=1$ so $x^*(\alpha)$ cannot be $\textit{strictly}$ increasing.
To get rid of corner solution issues, suppose that $$\text{Im}_{\alpha>0} \ \text{argmax}_{x\in [0,1]}\{\alpha f(x)-c(x)\}\subseteq (0,1)$$ where $\text{Im}$ indicates the image of the argmax.
This condition requires further assumptions. Assume beyond your given assumptions that, $f''<0$, with $\lim_{x\to 1}f'(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=\infty$. The condition $\lim_{x\to 1}f'(x)=0$ contradicts your assumption that $f$ be strictly increasing over all of $\mathbb{R}_+$. However, this is necessary for an interior solution over $[0,1]$ for all $\alpha >0$. We have a corner solution at $x=1$ if $\alpha f'(1)-c'(1)>0 \implies \alpha >\frac{c'(1)}{f'(1)}$. If $f'(1)>0$, then there exists an $\tilde{\alpha}$ for which we get a corner solution and for all $\alpha>\tilde{\alpha}$ we also get $x=1$ as a corner solution. This would mean the solution is not strictly increasing in $\alpha$ so we have to get rid of this behaviour.
Following Bertrand and BakerStreet's comments, assuming $f$ satisfies the above Inada conditions, any interior maximum satisfies the FOC $$0=\alpha f'(x^*(\alpha))-c'(x^*(\alpha)):=\mathscr{F}(x^*(\alpha),\alpha)$$ applying the implicit function theorem \begin{align*} \frac{dx^*(\alpha)}{d\alpha}=-\frac{\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{F}}{\partial \alpha}\right)}{\left(\frac{\partial \mathscr{F}}{\partial x}\right)}=-\frac{f'(x^*(\alpha))}{\alpha f''(x^*(\alpha))-c''(x^*(\alpha))}>0 \end{align*}
Where the inequality follows since $f',c''>0$ and $f''<0$.
Therefore, assuming the solution is interior for all $\alpha>0$, strict concavity of $f$ is all you need.

Thanks! Assuming interiority it can also be shown that concavity is sufficient by rearranging the FOC to $$h(x):=\frac{c'(x)}{f'(x)}=\alpha$$ with $h$ strictly increasing and invertible, so the solution $x^*=h^{-1}(\alpha)$ is strictly increasing in $\alpha$, right?

@Joseph Basford Thank you for mentioning my comment!

@raving-bandit Yes, that is correct. That also makes the use of the Inada conditions explicit as they ensure $\text{Im}{x\in(0,1)}(h)=\mathbb{R}+$.
